# value from database is not display

Tags: php, mysql, oop

i have a function to display all the data, in table. the number of row return is correct(based on edit n delete button) but the value are not displayed.

```
public function viewAll()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT 'id','titleAnn','dateOpen','dateClose' FROM annoucement";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['titleAnn'];
                $dateOpen = $row['dateOpen'];
                $dateClose = $row['dateClose']; 
                echo '<tr>
                    <td><?php echo $title ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $dateOpen ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $dateClose ?></td>   
                    <td><a href="editAnnouncement.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><input type="button" name = "editAnn" value = "Edit" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="deleteAnn.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" onclick="confirm("Delete this announcement?");"><input type="button" name = "deleteAnn" value = "Delete"/></td>
                  </tr>';
            }
            $this->numrows= mysql_num_rows($query);
        }
```

only blank space appear next to the buttons

Comment: You are putting some PHP in you echo statement: `echo '<tr><td><?php echo $title ?></td>...'` => `echo '<tr><td>'.$title.'</td>...'.`

Comment: Once more, with feeling this time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 6):

You were echoing PHP within an echo.... concatenate and echo like so:

```
public function viewAll()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT 'id','titleAnn','dateOpen','dateClose' FROM annoucement";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['titleAnn'];
                $dateOpen = $row['dateOpen'];
                $dateClose = $row['dateClose']; 
                echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$title.'</td>   
                    <td>'.$dateOpen.'</td>   
                    <td>'.$dateClose.'</td>   
                    <td><a href="editAnnouncement.php?id='.$id.'"><input type="button" name = "editAnn" value = "Edit" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="deleteAnn.php?id='.$id.'" onclick="confirm("Delete this announcement?");"><input type="button" name = "deleteAnn" value = "Delete"/></td>
                  </tr>';
            }
            $this->numrows= mysql_num_rows($query);
        }
```

Comment: totally new to php :( tq!

Answer (score 3):

```
public function viewAll()
{
    $sql = "SELECT 'id','titleAnn','dateOpen','dateClose' FROM annoucement";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['titleAnn'];
            $dateOpen = $row['dateOpen'];
            $dateClose = $row['dateClose']; 
            echo '<tr>
                <td>'. $title .'</td>   
                <td>'. $dateOpen .'</td>   
                <td><'. $dateClose .'</td>   
                <td><a href="editAnnouncement.php?id='. $id.'"><input type="button" name = "editAnn" value = "Edit" /></a></td>
                <td><a href="deleteAnn.php?id='. $id.'>" onclick="confirm("Delete this announcement?");"><input type="button" name = "deleteAnn" value = "Delete"/></td>
              </tr>';
        }
        $this->numrows= mysql_num_rows($query);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe post the reason for the error and explain your answer?

Comment: @OllyTenerife you beat me by 15 seconds, I was going to edit my answer, just like you did, relax man. (I already upvoted your answer)

Comment: @user3701415 Thats concatenation, kind of  a glue that goes between two strings :)

Comment: @user3701415 the dot concatenates strings: $myString = 'This are '.' some strings '.' concatenated';